# Finding the no. of possible right angled triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles

How many right-angled triangles **with integer sides** have an incircle with radius $2013$?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you saying the inradius of a right-angled triangle is 2013? There are infinitely many right-angled triangles with that inradius.

Comment: It is only given the value of the inradius i. e.  2013 and we need to find the no.  of right angled triangles that can be formed with using that information.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for triangles *with integer sides*?

Comment: Do you mean no. of right angled triangle with different sizes or sides?

Comment: Yes , I mean with integer sides {different sizes}

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297169/is-there-a-way-to-see-this-geometrically/2297290#2297290) a related answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get there are
27 solutions
with $a \le b$.

Ultimate result:

If the inradius is $r$
and the legs $a$ and $b$,
all solutions
with $a \le b$ are:
for each divisor $d$
of $2r^2$
such that
$1
\le d
\lt r\sqrt{2}
$,
$a = 2r+d,
b = 2r+\frac{2r^2}{d}
$.

Therefore,
the number is
$\frac12\tau(2r^2)$,
where
$\tau(n)$ is the
number of divisors of $n$.

If $n = \prod_{p_i|n} p_i^{a_i}
$,
then
$\tau(n)
=\prod (a_i+1)
$.

If $r$ is odd,
then
$\tau(2r^2)
=2\prod_{p_i|r} (2a_i+1)
$
so the number is
$\prod_{p_i|r} (2a_i+1)
$.

Since $2013 = 3\cdot 11\cdot 17$,
the number is
$3^3 = 27$.

If $r$ is even,
$r = 2^em$,
where $m$ is odd,
$\tau(2r^2)
=\tau(2^{2e+1}m^2)
=(2e+2)\tau(r^2)
$
so the number of solutions is
$(e+1)\tau(r^2)
$.

The derivation:

If the inradius and sides of a right triangle are
$r,a,b,c$,
then $r(a+b+c)
=ab$.

Assume $a \le b$.

We have
$r(a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2})
=ab$.

Since $a \le b$,
$ab
\ge r(2a+a\sqrt{2})
= ra(2+\sqrt{2})
$
or
$b
\ge r(2+\sqrt{2})
$.

Similarly,
$ab
\le r(2b+b\sqrt{2})
= rb(2+\sqrt{2})
$
or
$a
\le r(2+\sqrt{2})
$.

Therefore
$\dfrac{a}{r}
\le 2+\sqrt{2}
\le \dfrac{b}{r}
$.

Rearrange to get
$r\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
=ab-r(a+b)
$.

Squaring,
$r^2(a^2+b^2)
=a^2b^2-2rab(a+b) +r^2(a^2+2ab+b^2)
$.

Simplifying,
$0
=a^2b^2-2rab(a+b) +2abr^2
$.

Canceling $ab$,
$0
=ab-2r(a+b) +2r^2
=ab-2ra-2rb +2r^2
=b(a-2r)-2r(a-r)
$,
or
$b
=\dfrac{2r(a-r)}{a-2r}
=r\dfrac{2(a/r-1)}{a/r-2}
$.

Since this is symmetric in
$a$ and $b$,
$a
=\dfrac{2r(b-r)}{b-2r}
=r\dfrac{2(b/r-1)}{b/r-2}
$.

Also
$b
=\dfrac{2r(a-r)}{a-2r}
=a\dfrac{2(r/a)(1-r/a)}{1-2r/a}
$.

Since $b \ge a$,
if $x = r/a$,
we must have
$\dfrac{2x(1-x)}{1-2x}
\ge 1
$.
These are equal when
$2x(1-x) = 1-2x$
or
$2x^2-4x+1=0
$
or
$x
=\dfrac{4\pm\sqrt{16-8}}{4}
=\dfrac{2\pm\sqrt{2}}{2}
= 1\pm\sqrt{1/2}
$.

Let
$x_1 = 1-\sqrt{1/2}$
and
$x_2 = 1+\sqrt{1/2}$.
Thenfore we must have
$x > x_2$
or
$x_1 \le x \lt \frac12$.
Note that
$x_1x_2 = \frac12$
so that
$\frac1{x_1} = 2x_2$
and
$\frac1{x_2} = 2x_1$.

Since
$x_1 < \frac{r}{a} < \frac12$
or
$ \frac{r}{a} > x_2$,
we have
$2 <\frac{a}{r} 
\lt \frac1{x_1}
=2x_2
=2+\sqrt{2}
$.

Therefore
$b
=\dfrac{2r(a-r)}{a-2r}
$.

We have

$\begin{array}\\
b-2r
&=\dfrac{2r(a-r)}{a-2r}-2r\\
&=\dfrac{2r(a-r)-2r(a-2r)}{a-2r}\\
&=\dfrac{2r(a-r-a+2r)}{a-2r}\\
&=\dfrac{2r(r)}{a-2r}\\
&=\dfrac{2r^2}{a-2r}\\
\text{so that}\\
b
&=2r+\dfrac{2r^2}{a-2r}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
we must have
$(a-2r) | 2r^2$
and
$2r 
\lt a < r(2+\sqrt{2})$
so that
$0
\lt a-2r
\lt r\sqrt{2}
$.

Therefore,
for each divisor $d$
of $2r^2$
such that
$1
\le d
\lt r\sqrt{2}
$,
a solution is
$a = 2r+d,
b = 2r+\frac{2r^2}{d}
$.

Since $a \le b$,
$d \le \frac{2r^2}{d}$
so
$d \le r\sqrt{2}$.

As a check,

$\begin{array}\\
a^2+b^2
&=(2r+d)^2+(2r+\dfrac{2r^2}{d})^2\\
&=\dfrac{(d^2+2dr+2r^2)^2}{d^2}
\qquad\text{(according to Wolfy)}\\
&=(d+2r+\dfrac{2r^2}{d})^2\\
&=(a+b-2r)^2\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
r(a+b+c)
&=r(a+b+(a+b-2r))\\
&=2r(a+b-r)\\
&=2r(3r+d+\frac{2r^2}{d})\\
&=2r(\frac{d(3r+d)+2r^2}{d})\\
&=2r(\frac{2r^2+3rd+d^2}{d})\\
&=2r(\frac{(2r+d)(r+d)}{d})\\
\text{and}\\
ab
&=(2r+d)( 2r+\frac{2r^2}{d})\\
&=2r(2r+d )\frac{d+r}{d}\\
&=2r \frac{(2r+d)(d+r)}{d}\\
\end{array}
$

We know that
$d=1, 2, r$
are always divisors.
The values of $a$ and $b$ are
$(a, b)=
(2r+1, 2r+2r^2),
(2r+2, 2r+r^2),
(3r, 4r)
$.

If
$r = 2013$,
$r\sqrt{2} = 2846...$
and the divisors of
$2r^2$
up to this
(according to Wolfy)
are
1 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 9 | 11 | 18 | 22 | 33 | 61 | 66 | 99 | 121 | 122 | 183 | 198 | 242 | 363 | 366 | 549 | 671 | 726 | 1089 | 1098 | 1342 | 2013 | 2178 .

There are 27 of these.

Comment: Can you please proceed further?

Comment: I did. Wow, did I.

Comment: Yeah your answer is correct.

Comment: Is there any easy proof to get $2r^2$

Comment: NO, possible right $\Delta$

Comment: Annoying that mine is the only answer, acknowledged as correct, and no upvotes. Oh well.

Comment: please can you provide a more simpler proof to that $2r^2$.

Comment: I have tried but some how it get messed up.